# GSON how to understand 1, on, yes as booleans true?

Tags: android, gson

Is it possible to parse string using GSON and convert values like '1','on','yes' as booleans true?

So, I have class:

```
public class OItem {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Boolean is_online;
 }
```

And then I need using GSON translate it to OItem object

```
String string_json = "{id:200, name: Ivan Ivan, is_online : yes}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
OInfo = gson.fromJson(string_json, OInfo.class);
```

How to make so that some values will be treated as true, and others as false?

Thank you.

Comment: [Moved to my answer below]

Comment: @Delyan You should make that an answer...

Comment: Good point. It started out as a comment but it got away from me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid JSON. `{id:200, name: "Ivan Ivan", is_online : "yes"}` is valid but the `name` and `is_online` values are strings.

JSON is typed - all values are Strings, Numbers, Booleans, Objects or Lists and so that's what any (de)serializer will expect. Anything else will not be JSON and therefore you won't be able to use a JSON parser to parse it.

What you want to do is have getters in `OItem` that check the String value against a list of "true" values and return a normal boolean instead.